# Eclipse SVN projects not finding .class file

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have a java project in eclipse that was imported from SVN with the subclipse plugin.  If I attempt to add a class to the project, it won't create the .class file so it says "Error: Could not find or load main class"  The .bin folder is empty.  Any projects that I create outside of the SVN project work fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can be more specific in what situation that error message show?

Comment: Any project I download from the SVN repository works fine, unless I attempt to create and add a new class to that project.  It then gives me the "Error: Could not find or load main class" when I try to run the program.  When I look through the project folders on my system, there is no .class file in the .bin folder.  Now when I create a class in any project that wasn't from the SVN it has no problems creating the .class file and they run perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your Eclipse .project and .classpath files to your repository?  If you did not, then it is possible when you checked out your project was not configured as a Java project.  You would have to take the checkout option to use the New Project Wizard so that you could create the right type of project.

If you just do a checkout and there is no .project file in the repository then you get a "Simple Project" which will not have any Java tools or builders tied to it.